# is there any tool like Dameware, but for Mac?

Tags: mac, remote

we IT fellows must love [Dameware](http://www.dameware.com/) as we can control every PC from a single place, check definitions, security logs, alerts logs, check file system information, etc etc etc ... the list is so big that if I would tell you all the things I liked in Dameware, I would became a sales person after the talk.

**But now we have Macs on board**, specially for DVD production (all the bits and the bytes from coping the digital hollywood movies to send all with legends to cinemas in the entire country as we are the only distribution company.

> **How can I do the same that I can using Dameware, but in a mac?**

I know that Mac as the **Network Utility** and other apps, but I want to run all from the server, or my client station - it's ok if I need to administrate from a mac - so I can ask the boss for my own mac :o)

I also know about [Apple Remote Desktop](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/), but we need an OSX Server, and **we do not have it**.

As information, there is 2 Windows 2008 R2 Servers and all Windows 7 Business clients. All of the 5 macs have Snow Leopard and are using Active Directory to login.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple Remote Desktop don't require OS X Server, as http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/specs.html told :

> The administration and client system
>   for Apple Remote Desktop 3 is designed
>   to run on any computer running Mac OS
>   X v10.4.11, Mac OS X v10.5.7 or later.

Do you can install the Administration client on Mac OS X 'Client'

[Timbuktu](http://www.netopia.com/software/products/tb2/) is another option

Comment: Agreed. We use Apple Remote Desktop and the only way our servers get involved is as *clients* which ARD manages.